# Making a Controls.Add method call thread-safe

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety, invoke

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public void Inject(Form subform)
{
    this.tabControl1.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(subform);
    this.Refresh();
}
```

How can I convert the `Controls.Add()` call to a thread-safe call, using `Control.Invoke`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to make `Control.Add` thread safe is to make sure it's called from the UI thread.  This also implies that the `Control` being added is usable from the UI thread.

Here is a function though which produces a delegate which can add to a `Control` from any thread (presuming the added `Control` is OK on the UI thread).

```
public Action<Control> GetAddControl(this Control c) 
{
  var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
  return (control) =>
  {
     context.Send(_ => c.Controls.Add(control), null);
  };
}
```

Then for a given `Control` you can pass the resulting delegate to any thread.

```
// From UI thread
Action<Control> addControl = c.GetAddControl();

// From background thread 
addControl(subForm);
```

Comment: It's throwing an exception: *"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"* from the `context.Send`.  So it seems that the form is not usable from the UI thread after all.  I'm going to switch the logic around and have my main for go get the form object, instead of being handed it, and deal instead with the intricacies of the other thread accessing its child form.  I was just hoping I could "cheat" the subform into the main form, so it was still a first-class citizen of it's original thread.

Comment: But I'm going to mark this accepted anyway.  Thanks a bunch; it would have taken me a week to figure this out on my own.

Comment: @Robert If you are *very* careful with the `Form` instance and avoid doing anything that will call `CreateControl` you can create it on a background thread and then move it to the UI htread.

Comment: this seems a newbie question but ,where is the right place to declare the Action Extension method ,because declaring it on UI thread ,the method should be Static ,when declaring at UI Static Class Compiler produces error ,c does not exist in current context ? Please JaredPar could you provide an example on implementing this Function because i need that .